# Connection max pool size reached

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

i got the following error in my application.

> "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached. "

With out any idea i just changed compilation debug="true" to compilation debug="false" in web.config.

issue suddenly disappeared. is there any connection between compilation debug and pool size?

Comment: The thing is when you change anything in web.config and save it, the application pool is recycled and it resets the whole application. I would go find all db connections, readers and make sure all of them are closed both on success or on exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a connection leaking issue. It's important to always close / dispose connections  after use. Otherwise they are not returned to the connection pool (or returned too slow).

Make shure you always have using statements with connections such as:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
{  
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();  

    command.CommandText = "mysp_GetValue";  
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  

    connection.Open();  
    object ret = command.ExecuteScalar();  
}
```

[More information here](http://www.w3enterprises.com/articles/using.aspx)